# IIS Express SSL This webpage is not available

Tags: asp.net, ssl, iis-express

I have a ASP.NET MVC5 project running on IIS Express and Visual Studio 2013. I want to add SSL support to localhost for testing. I have followed the steps detailed in numerous blogs. Specifically [this one from Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx).

When I test my site via port 44300 I get the response "This webpage is not available" in chrome, "This page can’t be displayed" in IE and "Could not get any response" (response 0) from Postman.

I have confirmed correct binding information in applicationhost.config. I have confirmed sslcert bindings via netsh. I have confirmed urlacl bindings via netsh. I have tried running under Administrator privileges. I have disabled my firewall. I am at a loss of what to do next.

I have run IISExpress from the command prompt with Admin privilages. I got the following error :

iisexpress.exe /site:MvcApplication1

> Successfully registered URL "localhost:52033/" for site
>
> Failed to register URL "localhost:44300/" for site "MvcApplication1"
> application "/". Error description: Cannot create a file when that
> file already exists. (0x800700b7)
>
> Failed to register URL
> "https://*:44300/" for site "MvcApplication1" application "/".  Error
> description: Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
> (0x80070 0b7)

**EDIT**

I have deleted the urlacl binding for port 44300. It resolved the iisexpress command line errors... That said, when I run and view my site I still get no response.

Comment: I got it working. My path was wrong. I was navigating to localhost:44300 instead of https://localhost:44300

Answer (score 2):

I got it working. My path was wrong. I was navigating to

```
localhost:44300
```

instead of

```
https://localhost:44300
```